# Bundling different app versions in one React Native app

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an enterprise React Native project that targets customers' backend installed on-premises. Some customers are slower than others to upgrade the backend and we still need to support them.

Instead of using feature flags, would it be possible to set up a workflow so that:

- each release branch gets bundled as (e.g. release-v1, release-v2, release-v3,...)
- we configure the compatible app version on the backend
- the React Native opens up, fetches the compatible app version number, and loads up the appropriate bundle

Comment: Do you want to change the version of the application and have a different version for each branch then?

Comment: No. I want to bundle all app versions within a single published app in the app stores. Each app version (or each version branch) would be a separate bundle within the same app, and I'd switch between the bundles dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

With git you can group different branches that hold different versions of your app:

**ANDROID:**

path: yourProject/android/app/build.gradle

search and change: "versionCode" and "versionName"

**iOS:**

- Open xCode
- Select app project
- Go to "General"
- Change "version"

**If you need get app version from Javascript use "react-native-version-info":**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-version-info

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is not the solution I'm looking for, as I understand it, your solution proposes to build separate apps for separate versions, whereas I'd like to build a single app and switch between different bundles based on which version I need.

Comment: Ey, So the solution with git mentioned first doesn't fit your problem either?

Comment: I just updated my answer to fit the question better so we analyze

Answer (score -1):

You could organise your codebase so that it is flexible for all the different 'flavours' of the app.

For example:

- `Main` code branch (all your base code goes in here, shared functionality, etc..)

  - Branch `v1` - the differences on top of your 'main' branch for this version
  - Branch `v2` - as v1 but with specific changes for v2 users
  - Branch `N` - ...and so on

Then each `Branch 1,2,N` version of the app can have it's own bundle Id and be released as a separate app.
You have 1 codebase to work on. Updates can be made on `main` and trickled down to `Branch N` apps if needed.
Specific "Branch" updates can be made and pushed to the relevant code branch.